# ORA-12705: invalid or unknown NLS parameter value specified

Tags: oracle, jboss, odbc, jdbc

I have a J2EE application hosted on JBoss on Linux.

When I try to access the application, I see following error in the `server.log` file.

```
ORA-12705: invalid or unknown NLS parameter value specified
```

When I point the same JBoss instance to a different schema, the application works fine.

I tried to go through a few forums and found that the NLS parameter settings are fine.

Can anyone help.

- Jboss version = 4.0.2
- DB version = oracle 10.2

output of locale command on linux

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: When you say "When I point the same jboss instance to a different schema" do you really mean a different instance?

Comment: And, what is the value of your NLS_LANG environment variable?

Comment: @DCookie. NLS_LANG environment variable is not set. Also to answer your previous query I point the same app instance to a different database schema.

Comment: I'm not talking about your app instance. I find it hard to believe you can have this kind of problem connecting as a different user/schema to a particular database instance. This seems to be a client/server issue, not a user/schema issue.

Comment: @DCookie. Thats the exact problem. if I point the same jboss app instance to a different schema on the same db it works fine.

Comment: Does that Schema maybe have a logon trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Make sure en_US.UTF-8 is installed. It should appear in the list generated by "locale -a". If it isn't you'll need to install it.
2. export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
3. export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8

Comment: @DCookie. I can try this, But if these settings are important to have my app work. how does it work when pointed to a different schema.